# Telling the Difference between Custom Content Types versus Default Content Types?

Tags: experience-manager

As an XPM user, how can you tell which are Custom Content Types versus the default ones (that XPM determines based on the CPs on the page)?

[image: Available Content Types]

[image: Custom versus Default Content Types]

So far I know Custom Content Types could have a description. So if there is a description, it's not a Default Content Type. :-) You can also match the TCM URLs to see which are already on the page.

**Do you know or have you noticed if they display in a consistent order (e.g. Custom always before Default)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I think your developers should clean up these defaults, that could done by:

- removing them
- modifying them to ensure they are useful / based on the correct CT etc

I wouldn't want XPM to show me a list of some items that are default vs some custom, the build should be tailored to the users of the system (set these on PTs).

Comment: +1-- tip on your first point for anyone that reads this: the default option is set in Inline Editing settings (from the Slide Out Navigation) for a given Publication and its Page Templates. So we can't "delete" them per se, but we can *uncheck* them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but I thought the Content Types are ordered alphabetically, and then custom ones first, default ones separate.

However as a best practice if you went through the route of creating custom Content Types, by all means, do them all. Default Content Types will only appear if there is content on the  Page (based on a certain Schema) where there is no custom Content Type available.

Comment: Hmm, I get the defaults in alphabetical order (maybe). But not the custom Content Types--unless it's based on the prototyped Component (I'll test some more). I get both Custom *and* defaults, so I'm not sure on your last point but I agree with you and John that we should create Custom Content Types as a best practice.